# Unable to stop Launch of activity onLongPress

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android Development, was trying out `RecyclerView`. I have created NavigationDrawer further a fragment under which I'm trying to implement onClick and onLongPress using `onSingleTap` and `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Now, I tried to :

> Launch an Activity from single Click, and to show a Snackbar for onLongPress but when I LongPress, it does shows me Snackbar but then Launches the Activity defined for Single Click.

```
package com.thenewboston.mynavigation;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;



public class ToolFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RelativeLayout tool_layout;


String[] country = {"Dog", "Car", "Donkey", "WTH", "Lion", "Cat", "Football", "abc", "bcd", "sdad", "srgs",
        "gkgkf", "dtfhfy", "Hyynw", "CBSE", "vtu"};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tool, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    tool_layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tool_layout);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(country);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onmyClick(View view, int position) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "onClick " + position, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null)
                    .show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), InnerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

        @Override
        public void onmyLongClick(View view, int position) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "onLongPress " + position, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null)
                    .show();

        }
    }));

    return rootView;

}


class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {


    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;    // initialise the clickListener in constructor


    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {

        this.clickListener = clickListener;

        //Manually start gesture detector
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;    //this has to be true
            }


            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onmyLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        //single click method goes here
        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onmyClick(child, rv.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
        }
        return false;


    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

}


public interface ClickListener {

    void onmyClick(View view, int position);

    void onmyLongClick(View view, int position);
}


}
```

`Don't mind the Country names :)`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you are calling

> ```
>         clickListener.onmyClick(child, rv.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
> ```

in

> ```
> public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
> ```

By doing that, you are passing the event to the gesture listener AND you call the onmyClick method every time.

Basically, you call onmyClick every motion event, regardless of its type. If you want to go with this route, you need to keep some state in order to track the motion event and understand if it is a simple down event or a long press.

Comment: Agreed, but where shall i call it then? Inside `onSingleTapUp()` ?